# Select objects with negative conditions on association and groups associated

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I guess I wasn't very clear in the title, but I find it hard to describe *exactly* what I'm after. So it's better to start with an example:

I have the following models:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :learnt_items, as: :learnable
  has_many :trained_items, as: :learnable
end

class LearntItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :learnable, polymorphic: true
end

class TrainedItem < LearntItem
end
```

If, for example, I select all songs that have trained items:

```
Song.joins(:trained_items)
```

I would see (roughly) records returned like:

```
learnable_type | learnable_id | type        | label
Song           | 1            | TrainedItem | happy
Song           | 1            | TrainedItem | sad
Song           | 1            | TrainedItem | lively
Song           | 2            | TrainedItem | lively
```

If I would like to select all songs that have trained items **with** specific labels, I'd do:

```
Song.joins(:trained_items).where(learnt_items: { label: [:happy, :sad] })
```

Now, I need to get all songs that **don't** have trained items for given labels. One would think the following would suffice:

```
Song.joins(:trained_items).where.not(learnt_items: { label: [:happy, :sad] })
```

But this will still produce the following records:

```
learnable_type | learnable_id | type        | label
Song           | 1            | TrainedItem | lively
Song           | 2            | TrainedItem | lively
```

which is indeed not what I intended. You can see that the query filtered out records with the given labels, but the one with `label = 'lively'` is still there, hence returning the song with `id = 1`. I would need only the song with `id = 2` to be returned from this query.

How can I build a query with ActiveRecord so that my scenario is fulfilled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to find the `id`s you don't want and use those in the `where.not` condition:

```
Song.joins(:trained_items)
    .where.not(learnable_id: Song.select(:learnable_id).where(learnt_items: { label: [:happy, :sad] })
```

Comment: I get an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column songs.learnable_id does not exist`.

Comment: @AndreiHorak: Without the exact schema it's a bit hard to tell, but I'm guessing `learnable_id` comes from the `trained_items` table? If so, you probably need to add `.joins(:trained_items)` to the inner query (ie `Song.joins(:trained_items).select(:learnable_id).where(…)`).

Comment: I had to slightly adapt your answer to make it work: `Song.joins(:trained_items).where.not(learnt_items: { learnable_id: Song.joins(:trained_items).select(:id).where(learnt_items: { label: [:happy, :sad] })}).uniq`. I previously settled on using two scopes (meaning two separate queries), but I guess your answer is more performant since it performs only a query (which has a nested subquery).